# Batch read file that contains greater / lower than signs / carets

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

Alright, so I'm trying to read all lines from a text file. My current way is:

```
FOR /F "delims=0123456789 tokens=1,*" %%F IN ('find /v /n "" ^< myFile.bat') DO (
    SET line = %%G
    :: ^ Syntax errors at this line
    SET line=!line:~1!
    :: Yes, I have delayed expansions enabled due to a lot of fors and ifs needed
)
```

Basically the input file is another batch file which also contains the exact same code as above and other code with <, >, ^ etc. Once I read a line, it's basically impossible to use `%%G` as it will expand to stuff like:

```
SET line=ECHO Hello >> someFile
```

or

```
SET line=FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) ( SET "line=ECHO Hello %%G" & call :something & >nul SET /P =. )
```

Which will obviously not work. I've tried many workarounds (all have failed), including:

```
SET line="%%G
```

Which (most of the time) works, but from there using is with basically anything is near-impossible, even with something like:

```
:fixLine
SET line=%line:^=^^^^%
SET line=%line:<=^^^<%
SET line=%line:>=^^^>%
SET line=%line:'=^^^'%
SET line=%line:~2%
GOTO :returnFixLine
```

But all methods fail in some case or another. How can I read a file containing a batch script from another batch script, including special characters?

**EDIT:**
Doing

```
SET "line=%%G"
```

won't work, as %%G can contain quotes, and even if it doesn't, carets are still special in quotes:

```
SET "line=ECHO ^<Hello^>"
```

will turn into

```
SET "line=ECHO <Hello>"
```

Also, lines containing exclamation marks will get expanded too.

Comment: Why do you set a variable named "line " with a value of " (fileContent)" in the first snippet?

Comment: @SteveFest I'm trying to have a BAT file reading another BAT file. I'm not aware of any other ways of handling the data just read (%%G) with anything other than SET (for example substring).

Comment: `"String "" "` becomes `String ""`?

Comment: With `tokens=1,*`, there will be two replacement variable available to the `DO` part of the for statement.  One for the first match and the other for everything else on the line.  I don't think you need the `delims=0123456789`, but you do need `%%F%%G` to capture the entire line.

Comment: @SteveFest, your answer seemed to be very close, just edit and test it, then post it back up, so I can remove my down-vote from it.

Comment: @Chaoz, what exactly are you wanting to do with the content of `MyFile.bat`? _If you just wanted to read it then you could simply use `Type` or `More`!_

Answer (score 1):

The first problems are the spaces in `set line = %%G`, as you set the variable `line<space>` instead of `line`.
And you prefix to the content a space.

You should use `set line=%%G` instead, but even that produces sometimes problems, when spaces are behind the `%%G` they are appended.
The best way is to use the extended SET syntax `set "line=%%G"`.

Btw. There exists only one special charcter which can fail with a FOR-parameter expansion, that is the exclamation mark when delayed expansion is enabled.

The solution is to toggle delayed expansion.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims= tokens=*" %%F IN ('find /v /n "" ^< myFile.bat') DO (
    SET "line=%%F"

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET "line=!line:*]=!"
    echo(Testoutput: !line!
    endlocal
)
```